# What is the benefit of using formal terms instead of informal ones?

Tags: conventions

I understand that sometimes formal terms are superior to informal terms because they're sometimes more specific or succinct, but oftentimes this doesn't seem the case. In those cases, what is the benefit of using formal terms instead of informal ones? Here are some examples:

- Get is less formal than obtain, even though get is more succinct and they both seem equally specific.
- Quote is less formal than citation, even though quote is more succinct.
- Blow up is less formal than explode, even though neither seems more specific of succinct than the other.
- Seems is less formal than appears.
- Let is less formal than permit, even though let is more succinct.

Thanks.

Comment: Just so you're aware, there is nothing holy about "succinct" which makes it the single most desirable goal for any given piece of writing. Sometimes you *don't* want the shortest route between two points.

Comment: Pedantic disagreement: "blow up" is neither more specific nor succinct than "explode". The former could potentially mean "inflate", so context is required to be specific, which inherently makes it less succinct, as well. The latter really only means one thing. :)

Comment: I see your point, Zayne.

Comment: I know, Lauren Ipsum. However, I am aware that being succinct is generally desirable, so I'm asking what benefits the formal terms have that outweigh that they're less succinct. Also, when do you ever not want to be succinct?

Comment: "Quote" and "citation" have different primary meanings.

Comment: In general, "politer" phrasings tend to be longer phrasings, tend to be more formal phrasings, and tend to use words derived from Norman French, Latin, and Greek (as opposed to Anglo-Saxon).

Comment: @Jasper Regardless of if some of my examples is incorrect, there is still a general trend of the use of some informal terms being discouraged, even though they are no less specific and succinct than formal ones.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k -- You are probably overestimating the importance of succinctness as a reason for using formal terms.

Comment: @Jasper But succinctness does have _some_ value, right? Since some of the informal terms are more succinct than the corresponding formal terms, and the informal terms otherwise seem just as good, why would one ever use the formal terms? What benefit do the formal terms have?

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k -- Succinctness has great value.  Part of the value is clarity.  Too many words results in confusion.  Another benefit is that "straight-talk" makes you seem honest; "gobbledygook" and ifs, ands, and buts make you seem "like you have something to hide."

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k -- English is actually a few languages, one on top of the other.  The most important are 1) The "common speech" of "ordinary people", which is mostly derived from Anglo-Saxon; 2) The "educated" language of the lawyers, the bureacracy, and the "upper classes", which is mostly derived from Norman French and Latin; 3) "scientific terminology", which was mostly coined from Latin and Greek roots; and 4) "street slang", which differs greatly from "Standard English".

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k -- If you are speaking (or writing) in "bureaucratese" (aka "gobbledygook"), "common speech" seems out-of-place.  Bureaucratese includes lots of "abstract concepts", and custom-defined words.  Common speech includes lots of words that have ordinary meanings.  Using "common speech" will make it clear how "obtuse" the rest of the "gobbledygook" is.  Also, people may focus on specific examples suggested by the ordinary words, instead of the abstract concepts that the bureacratese might be trying to distinguish or recombine.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k -- Historically, the more "formal" terms were used (or invented) by high-status groups.  For example, the clergy, the professors, the lawyers, and especially the nobles descended from the Norman French.  If an ordinary person wanted to make an apology (aka "suck up to") to a noble, or wanted to imply that they understood the law better than their fellows (aka "put on airs"), they would use formal language -- even if it was less clear.  The same phenomenon happens today.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, words tend to have a level of formality, and there are often words with the same or very similar meanings that differ only in level of formality.

While being succinct is a good goal in writing, it is not the only possible goal. Synonyms often have different connotation or tone, and sometimes we want to set a certain tone.

For example, consider these two snippets of text:

> The night was black as pitch as Sally crept fearfully across the glen. Ominous noises assailed her, and she cowered in terror.

And

> It was dark out as Sally walked across the field. She got scared at a bunch of strange sounds.

Both say essentially the same thing, but the tone is totally different. The first sounds like it might come from a horror novel, the second from a casual conversation.

We had a post on here about formal language not long ago. I couldn't find it again with a quick search. But basically, human beings consider some events to require formal language because they are very important. Formal language sets a certain tone. Like at a wedding, preachers sometimes say, "That which God has joined together, let no man tear asunder." It would mean the same thing if he had said, "Hey, these two are married now, it's like a God thing, so please, nobody do anything to break them up." Why doesn't the preacher say it that way? Because such informal language seems inappropriate to something as important and solemn as a marriage.

On that other question someone asked, Why do I need formal language? Why can't I just say, Hey, I know this is important?

For the same reason that in a horror novel you can't just say, Hey, what happened next was really scary. Just SAYING that something is scary or solemn or romantic or funny or whatever does not set the tone. You have to use appropriate words that really DO set the tone. Saying, "This joke is really funny" doesn't make it funny. Saying, "This statement is very profound and moving" doesn't make it profound and moving. Etc.

Comment: I don't see how you're analogy applies. Saying that that writing ok instead of OK is very important doesn't make it important, but neither does saying, "Thou who hath produced errata in the spelling of "OK" shall beget great misfortunes" doesn't make it important either.

Comment: Sure, because mis-spelling a word is not profound and important. You need a combination of content and tone to achieve an affect. Either alone is not sufficient.

Comment: @ Jay Why exactly is good content alone insufficient? Would one saying, "Yo dawgs, this here planet's goin to be turned to nothin' but rubble in a week!" and subsequently supported it with strong evidence be treated as any less important than someone who said the same message, but formally?

Comment: It's not that it would make the event less important. It's that people would consider your attitude inappropriate. Have you ever been in the military? I used to be a consultant to the U.S. military. When people are about to go into battle and risk being killed, or captured and tortured, the general doesn't say, "Well, you guys go on out and fight now. Try not to screw up and killed." No, they have layers and layers of formality, from saluting and calling each other by formal titles, to elaborate ceremonies when someone is promoted. ...

Comment: ... In an ordinary job, if you do well the boss might say, "Hey, good job on the Taylor project, Bob. I'll see if I can get you a bigger raise this year." In the military, there will be an elaborate ceremony where they present him with a piece of cloth and medal to pin to his shirt. It occurred to me at the time that all of that formality is seen as appropriate because these people are risking their lives, and treating it casually would have been seen as massively inappropriate. Ditto weddings and funerals and graduating from college, each in their own way.

Comment: So then communicating formally is not about communicating efficiently, but instead about communicating appropriately? Why is formal communication appropriate in some contexts?

Comment: Basically, yes. I suppose one could quibble about what you mean by "efficiently". If you mean, conveying the desired information in the fewest and the shortest possible words, then sure. Being concise in our speech and writing is certainly a good goal, but it's not the only goal. We also want the meaning to be clear. A fiction writer may deliberately drag out a story to build suspense. If a woman asks her husband if he loves her, "Yeah" might be the most concise response, but she would be much happier if he elaborated or at least rambled for a while. Etc.

Comment: RE why: Hmm, why are formal clothes appropriate in some contexts? Why do we shake hands when we meet someone? Why do we clap our hands at the end of a speech or performance? Why do lovers press their lips together? There are all sorts of little rituals that human beings do that have little or no practical value, but that are understood to express an attitude or emotion. Why do people do this? I don't know, that's just part of what being human is all about.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you happen to know if there is widespread acceptance of these traditions? Do you think there is any hope of abolishing them?

Comment: Is there widespread acceptance of using formal language at weddings and funerals, of clapping for performers, and kissing your girlfriend? Yes, there is very widespread acceptance of all these things. I don't know where you're from. Do you not see such traditions and rituals in your own culture? I'm not a well-traveled person, but I've seen, for example, books and documentaries that discuss wedding rituals in different cultures, and while the details certainly vary, I think you'd be hard pressed to find a culture where the people do not have SOME sort of formal procedure they go through ...

Comment: ... to declare that two people are now married. Is there hope of abolishing such rituals? My first question is why you would want to. They add richness and meaning to life. I don't know how you could without fundamentally changing human nature. It would certainly be an interesting experiment to raise a group of children and teach them nothing about such rituals, and see if they then proceed happily with a ritual-free life, or if they end up inventing their own rituals.

Answer (score 0):

**A low-class answer:**

It is good to write clearly and to-the-point.  It is smart to use words that people understand. Most people talk "informally".  Most common words can be traced back to the Anglo-Saxons and the Vikings.  Almost all of these words are "vulgar", and some are rude.

Most people who grew up speaking English know exactly what these words mean.  If you say something in plain English, they can imagine it in their heads.  This makes it easy to catch liars and scammers.

Some people talk in "street slang."  (For example, in "ebonics".)  They'll get yer point better if you talk like dem.  But I ain't good with that jive, so I might screw it up.  So I will stick to words I do understand.

**A formal response:**

Succinctness has great value.  When discussing science, legal matters, or other technical topics, it is convenient to use specific words with precise denotations and appropriate connotations.  Educated people, lawyers, bureaucrats, and scientists speak "formally" -- especially when they are creating regulations or discussing technical topics.  Many formal terms are derived from Norman French.  Most technical terms were invented by the intelligentsia using Latin and Greek roots.  Latin and Greek vocabulary is the opposite of vulgar.  Formal vocabulary allows even intimate topics to be discussed dispassionately.

Many "formal" terms are designed for discussing abstractions.  Furthermore, authors and lawmakers can precisely define what "formal" words mean.  This enables discussing things on an abstract level -- people are less likely to fixate on ordinary meanings of words.  Using formal terms lets people speak more subtly.

Injecting mundane terms into "formal" discussions can be distracting.  Rude words make educated terminology seem like "gobbledygook".

Comment: I understand that many formal and technical terms are better than other terms for discussing abstractions, but some formal terms, such as the ones in the OP, don't seem to have such an advantage. What do you mean by "hung up on"?